# jquery not found, ajax not found

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

[image]

[image]

[image]
I got the above errors while trying to open the web application on my server. and if i click add on these two errors then my applicaiton works for the users but if i click close and run the application and when the user clicks insert on the details view he gets this error:

```
     Specified cast is not valid. 
          Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

             Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

            Source Error: 



            An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. 
    Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. Stack Trace:
     [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.] WorkOrderManagement.CreateWorkOrder.RequestorSource_Inserted(Object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) 
    in C:\Users\israa\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WorkOrderManagement\WorkOrderManagement\CreateWorkOrder.aspx.cs:320 System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) 
+2801499 System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) 
+4114144 System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView.HandleEvent
    (EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +464 System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +70 System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewRow.OnBubbleEvent
    (Object source, EventArgs e) +107 System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +70 System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent
    (IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain
    (Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

---

i talked to my manager and he said something about a cross site scripting by i am not sure about what that is, so if someone has come across a similar issue as this and has solved it if you would please guide me that would be greatly appreciated.

The jquery and ajax that i am using in the application comes from the .aspx head section: that all the code i have that deals with this error, did you need anything else??

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Create New WorkOrder</title>
     <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="CssMenu/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .watermark
    {
        color:red
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Javascript Code with a function:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
         function Search_Gridview(strKey, strGV) {
             var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
             var tblData = document.getElementById(strGV);
             var rowData;
             for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) {
                 rowData = tblData.rows[i].innerHTML;
                 var styleDisplay = 'none';
                 for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
                     if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
                         styleDisplay = '';
                     else {
                         styleDisplay = 'none';
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
             }
         }
</script>
```

the above fucntion gets referenced as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup ="Search_Gridview(this, 'GridView1')" ></asp:TextBox></p>
```

how can i add the above java script to my project and reference in "onkeyup"??

here is the code for the requestor_inserted

```
 protected void RequestorSource_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            if (successfull == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    int newid = (int)e.Command.Parameters["@NewId"].Value;
                    TextBox13.Text = newid.ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    successfull = false;
                }
               if (e.AffectedRows == 1 && successfull == true)
               {
                   successfull = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   successfull = false;
               }
            }
            else
            {
                successfull = false;
            }


        }
```

.aspx of the datasource:

```
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="RequestorSource" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WorkOrderConnectionString3 %>"

                SelectCommand="SELECT WorkOrderNum, Requestor, Date, Department, CompletionDate, MachineDescription, MachineLocation, [Type of Work Order] AS Type_of_Work_Order, [Work Required] AS Work_Required, WorkOrderNum, Status FROM Master"
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Master] WHERE [WorkOrderNum] = @WorkOrderNum"
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Master
(Requestor, Date, Department, CompletionDate, MachineDescription, MachineLocation, 
[Type of Work Order], [Work Required], Status) VALUES (@Requestor, @Date, @Department,
     @CompletionDate, @MachineDescription, @MachineLocation,
     @Type_of_Work_Order, @Work_Required, @Status); 
    SET @NewId = Scope_Identity()"   

     UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Master] SET [WorkOrderNum] = @WorkOrderNum, [Requestor] = @Requestor, [Date] = @Date, 
    [Department] = @Department, [CompletionDate] = @CompletionDate, [MachineDescription] = @MachineDescription, 
    [MachineLocation] = @MachineLocation, 
    [Type of Work Order] = @Type_of_Work_Order, 
    [Work Required] = @Work_Required 
    WHERE [WorkOrderNum] = @WorkOrderNum"
                oninserted="RequestorSource_Inserted">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="WorkOrderNum" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="WorkOrderNum" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Requestor" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Date" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="CompletionDate" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="MachineDescription" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="MachineLocation" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Type_of_Work_Order" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Work_Required" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>
                <InsertParameters>            
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Requestor" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Date" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Department" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="CompletionDate" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="MachineDescription" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="MachineLocation" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Type_of_Work_Order" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Work_Required" Type="String" />        
                    <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />        
                    <asp:Parameter Direction="Output" Type="Int32" Name="NewId" />

                </InsertParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show your code.

Comment: Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration is enabled on server OSes by default so yo don't accidentally infect your server with malware.  When it's turned on, you need to whitelist each and every internet URL you visit, including any CDNs your app imports code from.  It should not be an issue on desktop OSes.

Comment: @dave see if this helps the error popus up on IE im not sure how i can provide you code regarding a popup but if your asking me for the code i am using regarding jquery and ajax i have added it back in the question please take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

The first two messages appear because the use of Internet Explorer is limited on a server for security reasons. You should not browse websites because if your browser gets "infected" your complete server is at risk.

The other problem happens inside the code of your web application, perhaps it does not contain valid data because of missing javascript libraries. But we only can answer this question when you show us the code of CreateWorkOrder.aspx.cs, several lines near line 320 could already be enough.

Comment: i agree not to use the servers browser but my manager said that instead of customErrors mode ="Off" i could see the exact error by logging in to servers browser thats when i saw these popups and asked him and he told be i need to add all the scripts to a folder in the applicaiton :()

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to leave only one reference to jQuery javascript in your page. Decide, which one "ajax.googleapis.com" or "code.jquery.com" you will use and delete the other.

Second, if you have reasons to avoid loading javascript from a third-party site, download a version of jQuery and make it part of your website.

Comment: i download the latest jquery and removed all "code.jquery.com" from my aspx page and referenced the downloaded jquery but when i deployed it on to the server and accessed the broswer i am still getting the same error all i can see that is still referencing javascript is the code i have placed in the question above that does an universal search on my gridview. so how can i copy the javascript function and reference it from within part of my website??

Comment: what does your `Search_Gridview` javascript function have to do with "when the user clicks insert on the details view he gets this error"? Show the code for `CreateWorkOrder.RequestorSource_Inserted`.

Comment: the error seems to pop up when i open the browser and the localhost url is entered to create a workorder on the server, my manager believed the reason the popup were appearing because i was referencing the code.jquery.com in my webform and ajax.googleapis and i deleted the ajax.googleapis after reading your solution, i download latest jquery version and set the src=" downlaoded file" the reason i was talking about the insert getting failed is due to the popups if i dont accept for the code.jquery.com to be added it still runs the application but the insert fails.

Comment: the only typecast in `RequestorSource_Inserted` is on line `int newid = (int)e.Command.Parameters["@NewId"].Value;`. Check what `e.Command.Parameters["@NewId"]` is. By the way, I don't see any jQuery used in the javascript code that you showed. Why do you need jQuery in this page?

Comment: i am using jQuery for the CSS Menu